# Make nuget package native dependencies to be copied in output directory

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, msbuild, nuget

The main point here is: I'm not the author of the nuget package, I'm just using it. In my case, it's Selenium, but it could be anything.

I have my project `BaseTest` which has some basic functions based on Selenium. I also have `Test1`, `Test2`, ..., `TestN` projects referensing this `BaseTest`.

Now I run tests and they fail because when msbuild builds the solution it doesn't copy native dependency `chromedriver.exe` and selenium fails with `chromedriver is missing`.

I have now two options to consider: I can add `Selenium` package to all projects thay may theoretically consume this `BaseTest`, or I can manually do `XCOPY` to all these projects. Both alternatives seem to be ugly.

Is there any better way to perform such an operation?

---

I didn't expect that adding file as content is working for transitive dependencies (according to [this link](http://blog.alexyakunin.com/2009/09/making-msbuild-visual-studio-to.html), for example)

However, it does. My changes in `csproj` are following

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\packages\Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.2.33\driver\chromedriver.exe">
      <Link>chromedriver.exe</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

It does work as expected. Thank to @sotn

Comment: chromedriver.dll or chromedriver.exe?

Comment: @marcel thank you, post is edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include chromedriver.dll into your project (like a code file) and set it's "Copy to Output Directory" option to "Copy Always"/"Copy if newer".

If you don't want to checkin the dlls, you can add it as existing link too (Add Existing Item -> Add as Link) and then apply "Copy to Output Directory" option to "Copy Always"/"Copy if newer".

Comment: imho this is even uglier. i've always hated to have dlls checked in my source control

Comment: @Alex I actually considered that answer, but I assumed that it won't work with transitive dependencies. However, it does. Finally, you can NOT include it in your source control if you add is as a reference. See addition to post.

Comment: @Alex you don't have much options with native dlls. You can add it as existing link though..